# How to convert the column year-month-day to year/month/day in Python

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert the `year-month-day` date format to `strptime` format (`year/month/day`)?

```
In[67]
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df.birthDate)
df['Date']

Out[67]
0      1985-12-26
1      1977-01-30
2      2003-11-22
3      1983-05-07
4      1983-01-29
      ...    
5640   1956-09-17
5641   1985-12-26
5642   1960-11-23
5643   1928-11-23
5644   1955-12-27
Name: Date, Length: 5645, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

above the df I created,so that's my dataset

I originally want to convert it to age because I'm doing a segment of customer report, but the code I applied didn't work, it requires strptime

```
from datetime import datetime, date

def age(born):
born = datetime.strptime(born, "%Y/%m/%d").date()
today = date.today()
return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, 
                                  today.day) < (born.month, 
                                                born.day))
df['Age']=df['Date'].apply(age)
display(df)
```

Comment: Could you provide some details/context + what you've tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO! We're going to need more details to help you answer your question. Can you provide a sample of the DataFrame by including the output from `df.head().to_dict()` in the question (and possibly the `dtype` of the column in question)? Also any code you've tried so far would be useful as well

Comment: If you're wanting to do this to a pandas column, you should say so,  The answers are different.

Answer (score 1):

Use the datetime module, here is an example.

```py
import datetime

input_date = "2022-01-09"

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

print(date)
```